# How can I duplicate a database using phpmyadmin?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I want to duplicate my database with phpmyadmin.

How should I proceed?

> phpmyadmin Version: 3.4.5deb1

Comment: Dump the old database and reimport it with a new name?

Comment: Export - Rename - Import

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16510615/1783439 seems like the answer.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Login with phpmyadmin and then:

1. Select your database that you want to duplicate.
2. Find the 'Operations' tab as per below screenshot and click on that
3. After selecting the tab you will see the 'Copy Database to:' section see screenshot.
4. Enter the new database name where you want to copy the database
5. Click on the Go button and wait.

After the process completes, go and find the new database created with all the data.

[image]

Answer (score 92):

Go to the database you want to duplicate and click the Operations tab. In the Operations page under `Copy database to` section enter the name of the new database and click `Go` button.

Comment: Wonder why this answer hasn't been selected O.o

Comment: maybe because it doesn't work if the "new" database already exists.  I have a testing server, and I want to bring the latest "live" database over into the testing one, but the above process errors, since the database already exists.  If I delete the database altogether, then will I be able to add my user back to the database in cPanel?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is something that has recently been added, but if I deselect "CREATE DATABASE before copy", it works perfectly.

Answer (score 7):

phpMyAdmin tool can be used to export and import databases up to a few MB in size, providing a simple way to duplicate a copy of a database using a different name on the servers.

**Exporting a copy of the database to your computer**

1. Login to the database that you want to duplicate using phpMyAdmin
2. Click the database name on the left-hand side of the page. (Don't
   skip this step — if you continue to step 3 before doing this, you
   won't be able to reload the database under a new name later.)
3. Select the Export tab
4. Select the Save as file option
5. Click Go

You'll then be prompted to save the database file on your personal computer.

**Importing the copy into a new database**

You'll first need to create the new, empty database on the servers using the account control panel. After the new database has been created:

1. Login to the new database using phpMyAdmin
2. Click the database name on the left-hand side of the page
3. Select the Import tab
4. Click the browse button under "File to Import", then select the
   database file from your computer
5. Click Go to import the database
6. List item

Hope this article would help you: http://support.tigertech.net/mysql-duplicate

Comment: when exporting the data base, I user custom export method so what is the function to use when dumping data (INSERT; UPDATE OR REPLACE) in theses cases ?:  
1) update new data base 
2) update data base already exist

Comment: How about goto `databaseYouWantToCopy` then go to `operations`. In the section copy to : Enter the name of database and `GO`

Comment: this only works for < 8mb tables. follow @MadhuraJayaratne 's answer for a bigger table

Answer (score 2):

Export the database from the "export" menu in PHPMyAdmin.
Open the downloaded sql file with a texteditor (like notepad).
Search and replace the file for all occurences of the databasename, and replace it by the new name.
Save the file.
Import the saved file via the "import" menu in PHPMyAdmin.

You now have your duplicated database.